# How do I copy PROD data into a sandbox - options besides purchasing fullcopy/partial data sandboxes

Tags: sandbox, unit-test

For our production Org and Connected App I've written four SOQL queries that are called via REST API, now I want to **test** in a test or staging sandbox.  I've set up a developer sandbox and as you know it is empty.

Is there a clever approach in exporting some of our data from our production org into my test sandbox? I obviously do not want to reproduce all this data by hand for our QE team.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: if you have a fullcopy sandbox or a partial data sandbox you can instantiate with prod data using setup | data management | sandboxes

Comment: just spend the money, man!

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using some type of data loader, I use Jitterbit's data loader which is free on the app exchange. For related objects, create an external id field on the parent and call it production id. That way you can export the parent data and import that with the production id into the external id field, then when you import the children records you can match the parent production id to this external id field.

Answer (score 5):

SFXOrgData is a pretty awesome tool for exactly this, but it will take some initial time to setup the copy the way you want it. It's free for data transfers 2mb and less, so it's usually just right for pulling a few random records out of a bunch of objects. You can also edit which data you want to pull, so if you are testing on something that might be better tested on specific scenarios, you can query for that data to be transferred over.

https://www.sfapex.com/